# how to reconnect to git repo

Tags: git, github

I have a project that I link with github.

Well I try some things to connect my project to AWS.

Unfortunately, it corrupts my .git directory.
So I'm not able anymore to save my project on my github.

Is there a way to recreate my .git directory to reconnect on my existing repo ?

I made a lot of modifications since the last time, So I just want to connect my local branch on the master branch on my git repo.

I remove the .git directory because code was change to try to link on AWS commitcode. Don't want.
I want to return to my github project.

thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, You should clone the repo again in some other folder and drag the changed files from your previous folder to your recently cloned folder and then stage them and then commit them and then push the changes. I think this is the only option left as recreating the .git folder and connecting it to remote repo may lead to loss of updated files.

Answer (score 0):

If you go onto Github, and clone your repo to your computer again, you can work from any branches which don’t have your changes. Otherwise, you can drag your changed files into the re-cloned repo on your computer and then push the changes.

Comment: If I use git clone, it says : fatal: destination path 'myproject' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Comment: You have to clone it somewhere else. (Desktop, Documents, different folder etc.)

Comment: Yes now your answer is like the other answer. I clone elsewhere after I drag and drop all my other files inside this new folder.